# Segmented Control in android like in iOS

Tags: android

I want to make a segmented control in android(like there is in iOS) to switch between genders. Do android provide such widget?

**Following is the representation:**

[image]

Comment: Why not just have two `ImageView`s?

Comment: Because I don't want to :3

Comment: "I don't want to" is not a good reason.  What you describe is best achieved with two views, your design seems to be flawed in relation to your problem.

Comment: And that was not the answer(no offence), the main thing I want to know is is it possible to do what I want? And two image views are not ideal for all cases. Sometimes, I need a single image with transparent views.

Comment: No, it was not an answer - it was a comment. ImageView is not a ViewGroup, hence you can't simply add other view to it.  You can do custom drawing and you can certainly add listeners.  Then in your listeners you can check the coordinates of the event and act accordingly.

Comment: @AleksG It is inside a Frame Layout. So, I can add views to frame layout.

Comment: @GrlsHu Check out my comment :)

Comment: I wonder why I am getting downvotes. Is the question not constructive??

Comment: (1) Your ImageView is inside the FrameLayout, but it itself is not a ViewGroup.  You can add other views to your layout, but not to the ImageView. (2) Downvotes, probably, because you are stubbornly trying to apply a flawed design to your problem.

Answer (score 1):

Try out as below:

```
  <LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/nl_rllayut"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:weightSum="1" >

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight=".5" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/nl_btn1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="MALE"
            android:background="@android:color/black"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white" />
    </FrameLayout>

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight=".5" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/nl_btn2"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="FEMALE"
            android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white" />
    </FrameLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

**Output:**

[image]

Comment: I don't want seperate buttons, I got single image as graphics and want to add views on it.

Comment: Either you make your own selector for both buttons separately and manage it based on selection or you get two separate image for selected and deselected images.

Answer (score 0):

Got a way to do this:

```
<FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/a4"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/a1"
            android:layout_alignRight="@+id/a1"
            android:layout_below="@+id/a3" >


            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:contentDescription="@string/cD"
                android:src="@drawable/signup_17" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal" >

                <View
                    android:id="@+id/signup_male"
                    android:layout_width="00dp"
                    android:layout_height="40dp"
                    android:layout_weight="0.50"
                    android:background="@android:color/transparent" />

                <View
                    android:id="@+id/signup_female"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="40dp"
                    android:layout_weight="0.50"
                    android:background="@android:color/transparent" />
            </LinearLayout>

        </FrameLayout>
```

The only problem is if I give fill parent to height of these views, they take the whole space of the parent (even horizontally), which is very strange and I can't figure out why.